# Segmentation fault in THTTPClient

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm having a strange problem with the `THTTPClient` component on android. when I put a `THTTPClient` component in a data module and execute my code everything works perfectly, but if I create the component at runtime a segmentation fault (11) error occurs when I close the application. I am using thread to access my server. This error only occurs when I close the app. I am using Rad Studio 10.3.1.

```
LThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      pegar: THTTPClient;
      ts : TStringlist;
      liberado:string;
    begin     
      try
        pegar := THTTPClient.create;
        ts := TStringlist.create;
        pegar.Accept :=
          'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
        pegar.AcceptLanguage :=
          'pt-BR,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
        pegar.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        ts.Add('email=' + username);
        ts.Add('password=' + senha);
        liberado := pegar.Post(caminho_api +
            'authentication/login', ts).ContentAsString(TEncoding.UTF8);
      finally
       ts.free;
       pegar.free;      
      end;   
end); 
LThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
LThread.OnTerminate:=terminate_autenticacao; 
LThread.Start;
```

But if I put the component in a DataModule and do that other way, this error does not occur:

```
LThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      ts : TStringlist;
      liberado:string;
    begin      
      try
        ts := TStringlist.create;
        datamodule.pegar.Accept :=
          'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
        datamodule.pegar.AcceptLanguage :=
          'pt-BR,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
        datamodule.pegar.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        ts.Add('email=' + username);
        ts.Add('password=' + senha);

        liberado := datamodule.pegar.Post(caminho_api +
            'authentication/login', ts).ContentAsString(TEncoding.UTF8);

      finally
       ts.free;     
      end;
  end);
LThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
LThread.OnTerminate:=terminate_autenticacao;
LThread.Start;
```

Comment: To be precise: [`THttpClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient) that you used in the first snippet is not a component. On the other hand, `pegar` that you refer to in the second snippet is [`TNetHTTPClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient) component wrapper around `THttpClient` that can be dropped on a form or data module.

Comment: See also [Automatic Reference Counting in Delphi Mobile Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers).

Comment: A common cause of SF11 on shutdown of a mobile app with a thread is that the app has shutdown while the thread is still running. To mitigate that, prevent the app from shutting down while the thread is still running.

Comment: OK Guys, but I need to create multihreads, each thread with a TNetHttpClient, but this memory error always occurs. Some idea?

Comment: With tidhttp this error does not occur, but tidhttp does not access https on Android anymore

Comment: @AlexandreR.Pires it does if you include your own copy of OpenSSL 1.0.2 in your app deployment

Comment: @RemyLebeau the correct file is "OpenSSL 1.0.2g Android.zip" downloaded from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ ?

Comment: @AlexandreR.Pires that, or the "AndroidOpenssl1.0.2h.zip" file in the https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/ folder (I don't know why it is in the Archive folder since it is newer)

Comment: @RemyLebeau very thanks, apparently it worked, but now I have an issue here, when I run my thread for the first time the debug shows me the following error: Project mobile.apk raised exception class illegal instruction (4)

Comment: Is there something wrong with this code?:

        pegar := tidhttp.create(nil);
        compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.create(pegar);
        seguro := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create(pegar);
        pegar.Request.useragent :=
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; PLUS Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Mobile Safari/537.36';

Comment: pegar.ReadTimeout := 60000;
        pegar.ConnectTimeout := 60000;
        pegar.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
        pegar.IOHandler := seguro;
        pegar.compressor := compressor;
        pegar.HandleRedirects := false;
        pegar.Request.Accept :=
          'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
        pegar.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'pt-BR,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
        pegar.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
        liberado := pegar.Get('https://mysite.com.br');
        pegar.Free;

Comment: But this error only occurs the first time I run the thread, then it does not occur anymore.

Comment: @AlexandreR.Pires you should have edited your question to add that code, not posted it in comments. In any case, the only problem I see in that code is the assignment of `pegar.Request.AcceptEncoding`. Get rid of that line. Let `TIdHTTP` populate the `AcceptEncoding` for you based on the actual capabilites of the assigned `Compressor`. But I doubt that is causing the "illegal instruction" error. Do you only see it in the debugger? Or does it actually reach your code at runtime? If not, then don't worry about it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I only see in debug, the app seems to work well. Thanks for you help. I love Indy :-)